# Using WordPress, have dynamic query, want to avoid caching the results

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, rest, caching

I *do not* want to turn off caching for a site, but I do want to avoid caching in some areas. Wondering the best way.

First, I pull data from an API to check the "online" status of an advisor.
Next, I store that (and any other data that may change) in a CPT.
At the same time, I store a random string of characters (that I can sort on later giving the appearance of random order).

I pull the data from the API on every page load, because I need real-time data. This makes me cringe, but I don't know any other way. This part isn't cached.

However, when I display the list of "advisors", I sort them by online status, then the random string. This is meant to give fairness as to who is above the fold, and near the beginning of the results.

Well, that is all generated with PHP, so therefore the resultant HTML is cached.

I read a bit about the WP Rest API, and perhaps that will help with the speed of the query, but that won't help with the cached HTML right?

So, regardless of how I query the data (REST API, WP_Query), am I to assume that I must iterate through the data with JavaScript to avoid it being cached by the Full Page Cache solution of the server?

If I use WP_Query still, and I use PHP to display the results, can I just call the PHP function from JavaScript?

Every page of the site will display some or all of the advisors (ex: homepage 8 advisors, the "advisor" page shows all, the "advisor" category pages, and 4 advisors in the footer of every other page), so it doesn't make sense to turn off caching.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct. You'll have to populate your list of "advisors" via AJAX if you want to circumvent caching. That way your site will continue serving HTML pages while staying somewhat dynamic.

Comment: Further reading: [AJAX in Plugins - WordPress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (while the title contains the word "plugins", the truth is that the same thing can be applied to themes as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not better of doing it with AJAX?

Or, I'm pretty sure there's like a line of PHP that you can add to pages so they won't get cached. Woocommerce sometimes needs this for example. I guess it depends on which caching plugin you are using. Which one are you using?

Or, for example WP Super Cache has an area where you can exclude certain pages from caching. Under Settings ->  WP super chache -> Advanced -> Accepted Filenames & Rejected URIs.